# R - In a character string, find a word given in first column of df and replace it by its corresponding word in second column

Tags: r, regex, string, replace

I am working on messy character strings (from OCR) and want to correct it. Let's say I have a string like this :

```
messy_string <- c("This is a long string with m-istakes I want to corect")
```

I exported a list of all words contained in this string so that I could manually give each word its replacement, like that :

| Raw word | New form |
| --- | --- |
| m-istakes | mistake |
| corect | correct |

Then I get the above dataframe with two columns : "Raw word" is the pattern I want to match and replace, "New Form" is by what I want to replace it.

I guess the solution is obvious, but I could not find a working code that would say : take "messy_string", parse it to find any form given in the dataframe first column, and replace it by the form in the dataframe second column.

Would you have any idea to make it work ?
Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very hacky option:

```r
library(tidyverse)

# original string
messy_string <- c("This is a long string with m-istakes I want to corect")

# table of fixes
fix_table <- tibble(
  "Raw word" = c("m-istakes", "corect"),
  "New form" = c("mistakes", "correct")
)

# split your sentence by space " "
my_words <- messy_string %>% 
  str_split(" ") 

# replace words in a list
my_corrected_words <- map_chr(1:length(my_words[[1]]), function(word) {
  
  if (my_words[[1]][[word]] %in% fix_table$`Raw word`) {
    my_words[[1]][[word]] <- fix_table %>% 
      filter(`Raw word` == my_words[[1]][[word]]) %>% 
      pull(`New form`)
  } else {
    my_words[[1]][[word]]
  }
  
})

# turn separated characters back into sentence
fixed <- paste(my_corrected_words, collapse = " ")
fixed
#> [1] "This is a long string with mistakes I want to correct"
```

Answer (score 0):

A base R option is using `Reduce` + `gsub`

```
> Reduce(function(x,k) with(df,gsub(RawWord[k],NewForm[k],x,fixed = TRUE)),1:nrow(df),init = messy_string)
[1] "This is a long string with mistake I want to correct"
```

where

```
df <- structure(list(RawWord = c("m-istakes", "corect"), NewForm = c("mistake", 
"correct")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, apologies for an extended answer. I propose two solutions:

- **Solution #1** works for cases where all mistakes are known and all replacements are known
- **Solution #2** works for large data sets where you cannot a priori know which words are incorrect and hence have no idea of what the correct words for them would be.

**Solution #1**:

We start off with slightly extended data set:

```
messy_string <- c("This is a long string with m-istakes and errrors tath I want to corect",
                  "this is another fawlty sentens")
```

Next we define the set of `replacements`using the function `setNames`

```
replacements <- setNames(c("mistakes", "errors", "that", "correct", "faulty", "sentence"),         # new strings
                         c("m-istakes", "errrors", "tath", "corect", "fawlty", "sentens"))          # old strings
```

Now we implement the replacements in the data using `stringr`'s function `str_replace_all`:

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
# convert the vector into a data frame:
data.frame(messy_string) %>%
  # create id for each string:
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
  # split the string into words and assign each word its own row:
  separate_rows(messy_string, sep = " ") %>%
  # perform the replacements:
  mutate(messy_string = str_replace_all(messy_string, replacements)) %>%
  # for each `id`...:
  group_by(id) %>%
  # ... put the words back into their sentence form:
  summarise(correct_string = str_c(messy_string, collapse = " "))
# A tibble: 2 × 2
     id correct_string                                                       
  <int> <chr>                                                                
1     1 This is a long string with mistakes and errors that I want to correct
2     2 this is another faulty sentence
```

**Solution #2**:

The prior solution assumes that *the mistakes are known and the replacements are known*. This solution makes *no such assumptions*. That is, it checks **each word for a possible replacement in a large dictionary** (given that the data is in English, that dictionary is in English):

Let's assume this is the data:

```
messy_string <- c("This is a long string with m-istakes and errrors tath I want to corect")
```

The dictionary we will use is part of the `qdapDictionaries` package:

```
#install.packages("qdapDictionaries")
library(qdapDictionaries)
```

This library contains, amongst others, the dictionary `GradyAugmented`, which we are going to use here. It's a pretty large dictionary with 122,806 entries!

To compare the words in `messy_string` against the dictionary entries, we will use the package `fuzzyjoin`, which provides a number of highly useful functions for joining textual data based on fuzzy, or approximate, matching. The function we are using is `stringdist_join`. What it essentially does is that it compares all possible matches and calculates a distance metric for each match-up, with values ranging between 0 (perfect match) and 1 (poor match). You can choose the closest match by selecting the smallest distance:

```
#install.packages("fuzzyjoin")
library(fuzzyjoin)
```

Central to the match-up is the function `str_detect`, which is part of the `stringr` package:

```
#install.packages("stringr")
library(stringr)
```

The solution is this, annotated step-by-step:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
# convert the vector into a data frame:
data.frame(messy_string) %>%
  # split the string into words and assign each word its own row:
  separate_rows(messy_string, sep = " ") %>%
  # create id for each word:
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
  # perform the join:
  stringdist_join(
    # join the two data frames:
    ., data.frame(GradyAugmented),
    # by ...
    by = c("messy_string" = "GradyAugmented"),
    # use left join:
    mode = 'left',
    # use Jaro-Winkler distance metric:
    method = "jw",
    # enable case-insensitive matching:
    ignore_case = TRUE,
    # maximum distance:
    max_dist = 0.1,
    # name for distance column:
    distance_col = 'dist') %>% 
  # group by id:
  group_by(id) %>%
  # only show single-closest match:
  slice_min(order_by = dist, n = 1) %>%
  ungroup()
```

The result:

```
# A tibble: 13 × 4
   messy_string    id GradyAugmented   dist
   <chr>        <int> <chr>           <dbl>
 1 This             1 this           0     
 2 is               2 is             0     
 3 a                3 a              0     
 4 long             4 long           0     
 5 string           5 string         0     
 6 with             6 with           0     
 7 m-istakes        7 mistakes       0.0370
 8 and              8 and            0     
 9 tath            10 tat            0.0833
10 I               11 i              0     
11 want            12 want           0     
12 to              13 to             0     
13 corect          14 correct        0.0476
```

As shown in the output, all mkstakes but one have been correctly replaced - the only exception is `tath` (an English non-word), which was matched up with `tat`(an existing English word, as in "tit for tat"). Well, comparing random English text with mistakes in it against a large dictionary **will never produce 100% exact replacements**. But at least you do not have to bother to identify the incorrect words beforehand (an impossible task if your corpus is very large!) and can, perhaps, check the replacements that have distances > 0 manually!